# When a NPDA is constructed from CFG, how many internal states will be used for accepting any string from the grammar?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free, pushdown-automata, nondeterminism

> Options given were:
>
> (a) 2  (b) 3  (c) 4  (d) 5

This question was a part of my assignment. I think the answer is 2 **internal states - one start state and the other end state/acceptance state**, but I am not sure whether it is correct or not.
Please correct me if I am wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand the question, so I'd say it's a bad question, or at least badly formulated. Tell your professor.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends.

For every CFG we can construct an equivalent PDA with *empty stack acceptance* that has just a **single** state.

The construction is mentioned in wikipedia. We have single state $1$. For every grammar production $(A\to \alpha)$ add an pda instruction "expand" $(1,\epsilon,A,1,\alpha)$ which means "pop $A$ and push $\alpha$ without reading input". Additionally we have "match" instructions $(1,a,a,1,\epsilon)$ which means "when symbol $a$ is on top of the stack, we must read it from the input, while popping it from the stack". 
The initial stack symbol is $S$, the axiom of the grammar.

If we instead want *final state acceptance* then we need to distinguish a final state, so it is necessary to use **two** states.

Use a new initial stack symbol $Z$ to mark the bottom of the stack.
Just add two instructions, one to push $S$ on the stack $(1,\epsilon,Z,1,SZ)$, the other to move to the accepting state $f$ when the empty stack is reached $(1,\epsilon,Z,f,\epsilon)$.

This however assumes the automaton model that I was brought up with. Certain books do not agree, and consider PDA that start with an empty stack (*brrr*). In that case an additional state is used to start and push $Z$ onto the stack, so we need **three** states.